# EDM templates usage in Cloudpages

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Do you know, if we can use EDM templates as building blocks for CloudPages?

I tried googling the topic, but not many info online.

Best,
Paula

Comment: In my book, EDM is short for electronic dance music. Can you be more specific?

Comment: the acronym EDM stands for Electronic Direct Mail - also just learnt about it. sorry about that!

Comment: 'EDM templates' are subjective, e.g. you can have your brand specific EDM email templates or EDM social media post templates, etc. Usually these are custom too, and not universal boilerplates. Do you mean the email templates you are using in your EDM campaigns to be used as a base for Cloudpages?

Answer (score 0):

If your EDM templates use HTML or SSJS, then Yes! You might need some CSS to make it clean though.

Comment: Why are you specifically mentioning SSJS?

Comment: True that in connection to this question it was not the best answer, since you would not use this in email.

Comment: Are you not mistaking SSJS for JS? SSJS is executed in the backend, hence it can also be used in emails - however use-cases where this is applicable, are quite few.

Comment: Talking about SSJS alright, but as you stated, not many usecases are to be defined for email, that's why 'you wouldn't use this in email'. But as we are talking about templates to be used as blocks in Cloudpages, still worth a mention. Of course HTML is the main character in this play.
 Here's some doc on how to use ssjs in MC and how to use it: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_syntaxGuide.htm

Answer (score 0):

It will probably work, but it's sub optimal to say the least. I personally like to refer to Email-HTML and Web-HTML, think of them as the Portugese language and Spanish language. They have quite a bit of overlap and similarities, but they're both unique in their own way. The HTML structure of an email(template) is completely different then the structure of a Webpage. Dragging a random email block into a webpage template will probably result in the webpage not displaying the way you want it to.

Comment: Thank you Patrick!!